# How do i export grid to csv,pdf, xls in Agile ToolKit?

Tags: atk4, agiletoolkit

How do I export a grid to pdf or excel files? I have the next code, buttons of export are shown, but when I click one of those buttons gives me the next error:

Application Error: File not found

Exception_PathFinder, code: 0

Additional information:

file: misc\lib\Export\Advanced.php
type: addons
attempted_locations:
0: C:/xampp/htdocs/servidor/ATK2/modulos/costosUnitarios/atk4-addons/misc/lib/Export/Advanced.php
class: Export_Advanced
namespace: misc
orig_class: misc\Export_Advanced
C:\xampp\htdocs\servidor\ATK2\atk4\lib\PathFinder.php:207

Comment: The code is missing...

Comment: solved, i just update some lib stuff

Comment: Could you share your code? i would need it myself, but probably some other users also.. thank you.

Comment: if($crud->grid){    $crud->grid->addPaginator(5);

    
                    $crud->grid->addColumn('monto')->makesortable();
                    $crud->dq->where('estatus_id',1);
                    $crud->add("misc/Export");